# How do I use interact with MySQL using Java?

Tags: java, mysql

I'm assuming I need to use Connector\J and JDBC to achieve this, but I can't seem to 'install' Connector\J using the CLASSPATH thing. How do I do that ? I use the IntelliJ IDE if thats relevant.

I'm looking for a way to talk to a mysql database and execute and print out a few basic queries but I'm not getting anywhere because I can't even talk to the database.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might follow an example such as this one:

http://www.kitebird.com/articles/jdbc.html

But, you might want to consider using [Hibernate](http://www.hibernate.org/) unless you're doing only a couple basic queries.

Answer (score 4):

See [Using MySQL with Java](http://dev.mysql.com/usingmysql/java/) -- the first link from [Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=mysql+java).

Comment: Rich B is eliminating all lmgtfy posts. I have no problem with that, but I'd like there to be at least *some* content (not that there was any to start with, but people did upvote some of those answers).

Comment: Isn't it down to other users to downvote such answers rather than have RichB edit the answer into nonsense?

Answer (score 3):

I like [this tutorial](http://www.developer.com/java/data/article.php/3417381) because it's very detailed and thorough.  Pretty much every step from downloading and installing MySQL and Connector/J to writing and running queries is covered.

Answer (score 1):

Which version of IntelliJ?

You need to add the [MySQL Connector-J](http://www.mysql.com/products/connector/j/) JAR to your project dependencies.

Open your IntelliJ settings (the "wrench" in the top menu bar), go to "Libraries", click on "Attach Classes", and add the MySQL Connector-J JAR that you downloaded above.  That puts it in your CLASSPATH.

If you still have problems, it means you don't have the driver class name right.  It should be com.mysql.jdbc.Driver.